# Sticky sidebar to stop 30px above footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sticky sidebar, however I want to make it stop when he is 30px above #footer. How can I do this?

```
$(function(){ // document ready
  if (!!$('.sticky').offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists
    var stickyTop = $('.sticky').offset().top; // returns number 
    $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number 
      var CurrentWidth = $('.sidebar').width();
      if (stickyTop < windowTop){
        $('.sticky').css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0, width:CurrentWidth });
      } else {
        $('.sticky').css('position','static');
      }
    });
  }
});




        <div class="col-md-3">
<aside class="sidebar  sticky">

          <nav>
            <ul class="sidebar-links">

<li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>


        </aside>


        </div>
```

Comment: Is this your full code?

Comment: @dowomenfart yes it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add the `$(element).offset().top` to detect where the top of your footer is, then add a check to your scroll function.

This is the section we're going to add to the scroll function:

```
var footerAboveThirty = $('footer').offset().top - 30;

if (windowTop > footerAboveThirty) {
  $('.sticky').css({ position: 'absolute', top: footerAboveThirty, width: CurrentWidth });
} else {
  $('.sticky').css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0, width:CurrentWidth });
}
```

Here it is in context:

```
$(function(){ // document ready
  if (!!$('.sticky').offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists
    var stickyTop = $('.sticky').offset().top; // returns number 
    $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number 
      var CurrentWidth = $('.sidebar').width();
      if (stickyTop < windowTop){
        //NEW SECTION
        var footerAboveThirty = $('footer').offset().top - 30;
        if (windowTop > footerAboveThirty) {
          $('.sticky').css({ position: 'absolute', top: footerAboveThirty, width: CurrentWidth });
        } else {
          $('.sticky').css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0, width:CurrentWidth });
        }
        //END NEW SECTION
      } else {
        $('.sticky').css('position','static');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

## Update:

Also, be sure to include the height of your sticky element.  So this line:

```
var footerAboveThirty = $('footer').offset().top - 30;
```

changes to

```
var footerAboveThirty = $('footer').offset().top - $('.sticky').height() - 30;
```

## [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/07nj8ar8/)

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos – You need to change the `$('footer')` declaration to select whatever your footer element actually is.  So, try with the `id` of the element.  If your footer looks like this: `<div id="myfooter" class="footer">`, then instead of `$('footer')` you would use `$('#myfooter')`.

Comment: It seems that it works (through inspect element) but it works when the TOP part of the sticky sidebar reaches the top of the footer, and not the bottom of the sticky sidebar. I will update the answer now with my html code.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the bottom of the `sticky` element is above the footer with `30px`. And modify your check accordingly.

The code (make sure you update the FOOTER_SELECTOR according to your setup):

```
var FOOTER_SELECTOR = '.footer';

$(function(){ // document ready
  if (!!$('.sticky').offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists
    var stickyTop = $('.sticky').offset().top; // returns number 
    $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number 
      var CurrentWidth = $('.sidebar').width();
      var $sticky =  $('.sticky');

      var stickyBottom = $sticky.offset().top + $sticky.outerHeight();
      var footerTop = $(FOOTER_SELECTOR).offest().top;
      var moreThan30PxAboveFooter = footerTop - 30 > stickyBottom;

      if (stickyTop < windowTop){
        if (moreThan30PxAboveFooter) {
          $sticky.css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0, width:CurrentWidth });
        }
      } else {
         $sticky.css('position','static');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

.

.

....`stickyBottom`

Comment: updated answer & please make sure you update the `FOOTER_SELECTOR`. Should you want more help, you have to provide more info / `code`